# Jest unit test automapper nestjs

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, automapper, ts-jest

```js
jest.mock<CreateProductCommandHandler>(
  './commands/create.product.command.handler',
);
jest.mock<ProductRepository>('./infrastructure/product.repository');

describe('ProductController', () => {
  let productController: ProductController;
  let createProductCommandHandler: CreateProductCommandHandler;
  let productRepository: ProductRepository;
  let eventPublisher: EventPublisher;
  let commandBus: CommandBus;
  let queryBus: QueryBus;
  let mapper: Mapper;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AutomapperModule],
      controllers: [ProductController],
      providers: [
        CommandBus,
        QueryBus,
        AutomapperModule,
        CreateProductCommandHandler,
        {
          provide: ProductRepository,
          useValue: productRepository,
        },
        {
          provide: EventPublisher,
          useValue: eventPublisher
        },
        ProductRepository,
      ],
    }).compile();

    //mapper = moduleRef.get<Mapper>(typeof(Mapper));
    productController = moduleRef.get<ProductController>(ProductController);
    productRepository = moduleRef.get<ProductRepository>(ProductRepository);
    commandBus = moduleRef.get<CommandBus>(CommandBus);
    queryBus = moduleRef.get<QueryBus>(QueryBus);

    createProductCommandHandler = moduleRef.get<CreateProductCommandHandler>(
      CreateProductCommandHandler,
    );
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
```

Here is the controller class

```js
@Controller()
export class ProductController {
  constructor(
    private readonly commandBus: CommandBus,
    private readonly queryBus: QueryBus,
    @InjectMapper() private readonly mapper: Mapper,
  ) {}
```

Here is the Automapper profile

```js
@Injectable()
export class ProductProfile extends AutomapperProfile {
  constructor(@InjectMapper() mapper: Mapper) {
    super(mapper);
  }

  get profile(): MappingProfile {
    return (mapper: Mapper) => {
      createMap(mapper, ProductModel, CreateProductCommand);
      createMap(mapper, CreateProductCommand, ProductDomain);

      createMap(mapper, UpdateProductModel, UpdateProductCommand);
      createMap(mapper, UpdateProductCommand, ProductDomain);

      createMap(mapper, ProductModel, ProductDomain);
      createMap(mapper, ProductDomain, ProductModel);

      createMap(mapper, ProductDomain, ProductDocument);
      createMap(mapper, ProductDocument, ProductDomain);
      createMap(mapper, ProductDocument, ProductModel);
    };
  }

  protected get mappingConfigurations(): MappingConfiguration[] {
    return [
      extend(FzAbstractModel, FzAbstractCommand),

      extend(FzAbstractModel, FzAbstractDomain),
      extend(FzAbstractDomain, FzAbstractModel),

      extend(FzAbstractDomain, FzAbstractDocument),
      extend(FzAbstractDocument, FzAbstractDomain),
    ];
  }
}
```

I am using @nestjs/cqrs and a service class with automapper injected in controllers and service and trying to run unit test.

Mapper is actually an interface from @automapper/core.

I need a help on mocking and resolving the dependency of automapper. Because when I run the test it throws an error

`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ProductController (CommandBus, QueryBus, ?). Please make sure that the argument automapper:nestjs:default at index [2] is available in the RootTestModule context.`

Comment: can you show us `ProductController`'s constructor?

Comment: also, why did you have `AutomapperModule` at `providers`? modules should be in the `imports` array only. Show us that `AutomapperModule` as well

Comment: @Controller()
export class ProductController {
  constructor(
    private readonly commandBus: CommandBus,
    private readonly queryBus: QueryBus,
    @InjectMapper() private readonly mapper: Mapper,
  ) {}

@MicaelLevi, Agree Automapper Module should be in the imports alone.

Comment: @MicaelLevi please check the post I've provided the complete set of code snippet of controller, automapper profile and unit test. AutomapperModule is from the npm package @automapper/nestjs

Comment: looks like the module `AutomapperModule` doesn't have the required providers. Show us that module

Comment: @MicaelLevi as I said AutoMapper is an npm package. I have nothing to do with it.

Comment: yeah, I've been using that package just fine. I believe you should use the dynamic module, not that static one, that's why the provider was not found. As this is an unit testing, I suggest you to use [`getMapperToken`](https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/api/nestjs/modules#getmappertoken) instead of importing the whole module.

Comment: @MicaelLevi yeah got it. It works. Many thanks. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally with the help of @MicaelLevi, I implemented this and the mock works fine for automapper. The Automapper Profiles must also be passed in the providers section.

```js
  let mapper: Mapper;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AutomapperModule],
      controllers: [ProductController],
      providers: [
        CommandBus,
        QueryBus,
        {
          provide: getMapperToken(),
          useValue: createMapper({
            strategyInitializer: classes(),
          }),
        },
        BaseProfile,
        ProductProfile,
        CreateProductCommandHandler,
        {
          provide: ProductRepository,
          useValue: productRepository,
        },
        {
          provide: EventPublisher,
          useValue: eventPublisher,
        },
        ProductRepository,
      ],
    }).compile();

    mapper = moduleRef.get<Mapper>(getMapperToken());
```