How to mock/inject real Automapper dependency in module created with the use of jest automock
I try to mock automapper '@automapper/nestjs' dependency (but also am interested in passing real dependency) in unit tests of the service with the use of automock '@automock/jest':
In my service, I inject mapper using:
@InjectMapper() private readonly mapper: Mapper,
In the constructor. In my tests, I tried a couple of different ways but in general, I try to do it in the following way:
let mapper: jest.Mocked<Mapper>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const { unit, unitRef } = TestBed.create(FooService).compile();
    service = unit;
    mapper = unitRef.get(Mapper);
    // other dependencies of the service


The problem is that I cannot get a dependency from unitRef because TS2693: Mapper only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
Same as I try to use:
TestBed
   .create(FooService)
   .mock(Mapper)
   .using(/* trying to mock methods of the mapper */)
   .compile()

So my question is: what is the correct way to refer to the Mapper instance in this situation?

Since Mapper is just an interface, you can use it directly to mock it. You can use getMapperToken() function and provide new mapper for it. Looks like the similar issue was raised and resolved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75594531/jest-unit-test-automapper-nestjs
